# twitter bootstrap: activating tab layout after DOM is loaded

Tags: backbone.js, tabs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a tab container using Backbone JS and Twitter Bootstrap.  Essentially, I have a container view (that contains the tab navigation and the container div for the tabs themselves), and then each tab is a different Backbone view that gets appended to the container.

The markup before the tabs are loaded looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Tab views are appended to the `tab-content` div.

My problem is that the bootstrap tabbing layout isn't actually taking hold.  Instead of a tabbed layout in the container, I get a vertical set of divs.  It's basically as if the tab layout is being activated immediately after the container view is rendered, and as such, the appended tabs aren't factored into that, since they aren't part of the DOM initially.

I'm essentially looking for a way to call Bootstrap to activate the tabs *after* they have all been loaded into the DOM.  Adding a line like `$(".nav-tabs a:first").tab('show')` doesn't seem to fix it.

I know in jQuery UI you have to explicitly call a function to activate the tabs. Is there something similar for bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

The anchors inside the list elements need to have their href's set to the ids of the divs inside the tab-content class. The divs inside the tab-content need to have a 'tab-pane' class and an id referenced by the anchors.

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">tab1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">tab2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TVUPF/98/

Answer (score 0):

this might help: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/02/20/using-jquery-plugins-and-ui-controls-with-backbone/

in this post, i provide an example of how to work with control suites like bootstrap that are dependent on the elements being in the DOM.

there are a few different solutions for making this work.